# Why when I do sort by multiple variables, it only sorts by the last one listed?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

This is the raw SQL query I am sending

```
SELECT name, tags, components, metas, specials,
  array_length(ARRAY(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(components) WHERE UNNEST = ANY(ARRAY['a','b'])), 1) AS componentmatch,
  array_length(ARRAY(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(specials) WHERE UNNEST = ANY(ARRAY['m'])), 1) AS specialmatch,
  array_length(ARRAY(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(metas) WHERE UNNEST = ANY(ARRAY['v', 't'])), 1) AS metamatch 
FROM films
WHERE tags && ARRAY['a','b', 'm', 'v', 't']
ORDER BY componentmatch DESC, metamatch DESC, specialmatch DESC
LIMIT 5
```

If I understand correctly how it works, it should sort by metamatch, then, if metamatch is the same, use componentmatch and only then specialmatch.

However, it only sorts by specialmatch and ignores other criteria completely. I tried shuffling the order and found out that it always sorts by last criteria listed.
Am I doing something wrong?

P.S. I suspect that it might be due to the fact that I sort it by projected variables.

Query:

```
:components => ["c", "ca"], :specials => ["4/7"], :metas => []
```

Sample output:

```
{:name=>"Rydge", :component_tags=>[], :special_tags=>["4/7"], :metas=>["Lodge"], :tags=>["4/7", "Lodge"], :componentmatch=>nil, :categorymatch=>nil, :specialmatch=>1}
{:name=>"Ranada", :component_tags=>[], :special_tags=>["4/7"], :metas=>["Place"], :tags=>["4/7", "Place"], :componentmatch=>nil, :categorymatch=>nil, :specialmatch=>1}
    {:name=>"Nomads", :components=>["a"], :specials=>["4/7"], :metas=>["Place"], :tags=>["a", "4/7", "Place"], :componentmatch=>nil, :categorymatch=>nil, :specialmatch=>1}
{:name=>"Vido", :components=>["a"], :specials=>["4/7"], :metas=>[], :tags=>["a", "4/7"], :componentmatch=>nil, :categorymatch=>nil, :specialmatch=>1}
{:name=>"New Nomen", :components=>["a", "fa"], :specials=>["4/7"], :metas=>["Place"], :tags=>["a", "fa", "4/7", "Place"], :componentmatch=>nil, :categorymatch=>nil, :specialmatch=>1}
```

As you can see, it returns those rows that match specials, but components are ignored although they come before specials in sort.
P.S. I can assure that components values I am querying the table for exist in it, so they are not ignored because they don't exist.

Comment: could you provide example of output? it should sort by all columns in given order (first componentmatch then metamatch then specialmatch).

Comment: Hello.
I've just included a sample output.

Comment: The output has been modified from the query results: the query selects metamatch, but metamatch is not in the output.

Comment: *"it should sort by metamatch, then, if metamatch is the same, use componentmatch and only then specialmatch."* No, not at all, since your query says "sort by componentmatch, then by metamatch, then by specialmatch." Are you sure your query, question and results are in sync?

Comment: Can you supply a stand alone test case for this? The behaviour you describe doesn't match what should happen at all. Is there any chance you have columns named `specialmatch` etc in the *input* rowset? If you use `ORDER BY 6, 7, 8` (i.e. the ordinal column numbers) instead, does the result change?

Comment: Sami Kuhmonen, I just accidently shifted the order of columns in my sentence, that's all. "sort by componentmatch, then by metamatch, then by specialmatch" is what I wanted to say.
Craig Ringer, those values are integers actually. Sorry, not entirely sure how do I make a standalone test.
Wayne Conrad, I think I get your idea, but can you be more specific? I thought I can sort by any new variable generated by select...